# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'itemloaders' whilst deploying to scraping hub?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to deploy my spider to scraping hub but I keep running into this error with one of my imports. This works perfectly fine in development, just not when I attempt to deploy to scraping hub.

Import from item_loaders.py:

```
from itemloaders.processors import Identity, MapCompose, TakeFirst, Join
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
```

--

```
Deploy log location: C:\Users\denzel\AppData\Local\Temp\shub_deploy_nzoj_krm.log
Output dir not removed: C:\Users\denzel\AppData\Local\Temp\shub-deploy-wsvzk2w3
Error: Deploy failed: b'{"status": "error", "message": "Internal error"}'
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 267, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 347, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 73, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/app/__main__.egg/remind_me_scraper/spiders/listing_spider.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/app/__main__.egg/remind_me_scraper/item_loaders.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'itemloaders'
{"message": "shub-image-info exit code: 1", "details": null, "error": "image_info_error"}
{"status": "error", "message": "Internal error"}
```

--

```
└───remind_me_scraper
    │   items.py
    │   item_loaders.py
    │   middlewares.py
    │   pipelines.py
    │   requirements.txt
    │   scrapyd.conf
    │   settings.py
    │   test.txt
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───spiders
    │   │   listing_spider.py
    │   │   __init__.py
```

Comment: The error says that `item_loaders.py` is trying to load `itemloaders`.  I don't see `itemloaders` anywhere.  Is that a typo?

Comment: Oops thanks for the heads up, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I figured it out, I forgot to add the itemloaders module to my requirements.txt like such:

```
itemloaders==1.0.4
```